# How to solve for 3 variables with only one equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have the equation,

$$330x + 220y + 90z = 1540$$

Is it possible to solve for all variables, given just this one equation? The variables should be positive/nonnegative integers.

Comment: If you're looking for one specific solution, then no. You need three equations to arrive at one unique solution. But, if you're fine with any solution, there can be infinite possibilities.

Comment: This represents a plane in space, which has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Do you have any other properties for this equation?

Comment: You need to specify what values are allowed for the  variables.  Reals?  Positive integers?  What?

Comment: @thinkingeye I don't, it's just a trick question, it seems, from my brother's 6th grade teacher. I was thinking the same thing, but I wanted to make sure, so as to not look silly. The question is something along the lines of `Pete spent $1540, buying gloves, balls and hats at $330, $220 and $90 respectively. How many of each did he buy?` Thanks for everyone's response.

Comment: So, the variables should be positive integers (or, at least nonnegative integers)?

Comment: Yes, I would assume as much.

Comment: I see other methods than trial and error to solve this.

Comment: @MikeK You should edit the question and specify that variables are positive/nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 3):

Over the reals you can choose any two of them to be whatever you want and compute the third.

Over the positive integers we can divide out the common factor of $10$, giving $33x+22y+9z=154$, then note that $33$ and $9$ are both multiples of $3$, while $22$ and $154$ are both equivalent to $1 \bmod 3$.

We therefore need $y$ to be $1,4,7,10,\ldots$.  The solution is
$x=1,y=1,z=11$ and no other.  I found it by subtracting one each of $33, 22, 9$ from $154$ and getting $90$.  We can't have another three $22$s, so $y=1$.  Then we can't remove some $9$s and replace them with $33$s.

Answer (score 1):

$$330x + 220y + 90z = 1540 \tag{A}$$

Simplifies to

$$33x + 22y + 9z = 154 \tag{B}$$

Let $33x + 22y = 11(3x+2y) = 11w$ where $$w=3x+2y \tag{C}$$. Then we can first solve the simpler problem $$11w + 9z = 154 \tag{D}$$

Since $11 \mid 154$ and $\gcd(9,154)=1$, then $z$ must be a multiple of $11$. The smallest non negative multiple of $11$ is $z=0$, which gives us the solution $(w,z)=(14,0)$. The "slope" of the line, (D), is $-\dfrac{11}{9}$. So all possible non negative solutions of (D) are

$$(w,z) \in 
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
   (14,0) \\
   (5,11)
\end{array} \right\}$$

So, all possible values of $z$ are $0$ and $11$. To find the possible values of $x$ and $y$, we need to solve equation (C) for $x$ and $y$ given the possible values of $w$.

We start with $$3x + 2y = w = 14 \tag{E}$$

The smallest possible value of $x$ is $x=0$, for which $y=7$. Since the slope of the line (E) is $-\dfrac 32$, the possible $(x,y)$ values corresponding to $w=14$ are

$$(x,y) \in 
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
   (0,7) \\
   (2,4) \\
   (4,1)
\end{array} \right\}$$

We finish with $$3x + 2y = w = 5 \tag{F}$$

whose only acceptable solution is $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

We combine all of our solutions, getting

$$(x,y,z) \in 
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
   (0,7,0) \\
   (2,4,0) \\
   (4,1,0) \\
   (1,1,11)
\end{array} \right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation  $$330x + 220y + 90z = 1540$$ is the equation of a plane in three dimensional space with the normal vectro $$N=(330,220,90)$$.

In general, the equation $$ ax+by+cz=d$$ is the equatin of a plane with the normal vector $$N=(a,b,c)$$

You may find points of the plane by assigning values to $x$ and $y$ and solving for $z$